# Kolmogorov Smirnov test - correct data to compare against a standard normal distribution or not correct?

Tags: normal-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

The question arose from my analysis on Matlab.

The function kstest(x) compares data set x against a standard normal distribution (mean 0 and std 1)

My question is, do you correct the data set to have a mean of 0 and std of 1

y = (x - mean(x))/std(x)

or compare it without correcting?

Comment: This is covered in several posts already on site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need Lilliefors test. The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test uses a completely specified distribution, so in your case, you need to know exactly *which* normal distribution you're testing against (pre-specified values of mean and variance). Kolmogorov-Smirnov does not take into account the uncertainty involved in estimating the mean and variance. This is the issue that Lilliefors addressed in [his paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1967.10482916). From the abstract:

> The standard tables used for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test are valid when testing whether a set of observations are from a completely-specified continuous distribution. If one or more parameters must be estimated from the sample then the tables are no longer valid.

See also the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test) for a summary. The "nortest" package in R has the function `lillie.test()` to perform a Lilliefors test. I don't use Matlab, but from a quick Google search it looks there is a `lillietest(x)` function from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lillietest.html).

By the way, you might be interested in [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless?noredirect=1&lq=1) where it's discussed when (and if) normality testing is really appropriate/useful or not.